# Is imputation needed for $0$'s in regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, sas, data-imputation

I am working on a dataset of 2000 records using SAS Enterprise Miner in order to predict insurance payment (compensation) from insurer, a motor insurance company, to its customers. Though there are no missing values, there are a some $0$'s in the dependent variable *payment*. I would like to know if it is useful to replace these $0$'s with something else. Also, do I need to conduct cross-validation?

Comment: (1) I believe that Arab mathematicians settled this question over a millennium ago: yes, zero is a value.  (2) It depends on the purpose of the regression.  Perhaps you could explain that further?

Comment: It might be worth considering whether the zeros are true zeros (lack of payment) or if they are placeholders for pending payment/invoicing/etc.  If so, they might need to be treated differently.

Comment: Sometimes due to software errors, sometimes due to misuse of software by people values may be filled by zeros to mean "data not available". In such cases these zeros should be treated as missing values. For example the customer may be entitled to a payment but yet not have received a payment hence the system put a 0 there but it is wrong to take it as 0 for your analysis. Otherwise if they represent a true 0 value then you use it as it is.

Comment: Just to add to Cagdas' point, there's nothing special about 0. Some people code NA as -9999, or something else. If someone else hands off some data to you, it's always worth your while to investigate for strangeness of that sort.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose that in your case, the *payment* (which is settled with transfer of liquid currency) is a quantitative variable meaning you can take values from $- \infty$ to $+ \infty$ (provided values meet statistical assumptions and do not distort findings, *i.e.*, outliers) and you can split the unit into infinitesimally small fractions. So as of the first question, you do not need to replace $0$'s with something else. As of the second, if you want to address questions like *to what extent would my model yield accurate prediction?*. In such cases, you need to provide more information about study design.
Notice that in order produce robust results, you need to make sure the $0$'s are true $0$, *i.e.*, the insured has not been compensated at all. Sometimes *missing values* are recorded as $0$ and replacing these missing values with $0$ will considerably distort the results. Missing values might occur, for example, for past insurees who are no longer insured by your company.